# SSHRC scrip not working > Unexpected Operator

Tags: ssh, sh

I'm trying to make a little script in my sshrc file so it's executed when a connection is established.

```
ip="192.168.1.2"
if [ "$ip" == "192.168.1.2" ]; then
    exit
else
    touch /home/user/foobar
fi
```

But when I run it it keeps giving me

```
/etc/ssh/sshrc: 4: [: 192.168.1.2: unexpected operator"
```

and it executes the else condition

I thought this was how it's done in 'sh'

Comment: The double equals sign isn't strictly correct, though it is accepted by Bash. Try using a single equals sign.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.